# Null space vector and span of matrix

Tags: matrices, vectors

I would like to ask what is the relationship between null space vector and the span of a matrix ? or more specifically why does "a 2-dimensional null-space vector take away 2-dimensional span of a matrix"

p.s I am new to linear algebra and anything help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like you're thinking of the [rank-nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank–nullity_theorem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly, I believe you are slightly misunderstanding what the Span is.

Essentially, the span of a set $S$ (where elements of $S$ are vectors) is the set of all linear combinations of said vectors. In other words the term "span of a matrix" is not well-defined, but you can take the span of the columns of a matrix (or its rows).

Before we continue, let us define the Null Space of a matrix $A$. The elements of the Null Space are vectors $\vec{x}$ such that:
$$A\vec{x}=0$$
It turns out that we can write such a Null Space of a matrix as the span of some columns of $A$ (not necessarily all of them).

If $A$ turns out to be linearly independent, then there will be no such vector, and the Null Space only contains the $\vec{0}$ vector, and as such the dimension of the Null Space of $A$ is 0.

When you say "a 2-dimensional null-space vector take away 2-dimensional span of a matrix", I believe you are referring to an intuition for what we call the Rank-Nullity Theorem, which says that if $T:V\rightarrow W$ is a linear transformation (a matrix), then:
$$dim(Range(T))+dim(Null(T)) = dim(V)$$

The range of $T$ is essentially the span of all the columns of $T$, and so if the dimension of the Null Space is non-zero, this essentially means that the number of linearly independent vectors that spans $Range(T)$ is $dim(V)-dim(Null(T))$.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation

Comment: No problem, let me know if you need any further clarification! If you think that this answered your question, please consider marking this as answered/best answer! Thanks and have a great day!